# Searching for invalid or deleted user id with "user:" operator give unexpected results

Tags: bug, search

Trying to [search for a username doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3AFakeUserName) gives back list of all questions and answers on Stack Overflow:

[image: all posts given as search result]

Expected behavior is a 404 Page Not Found error, or a message like "We couldn't find the user, so here are the top Q&A on this site".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 7):

`user:` takes the numeric userid, not a name. E.g. you can search through your own posts with [`user:156151`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A156151). When you don't use a numeric argument (such as `user:FakeUserName`), the filter is ignored entirely, as if you didn't enter a search at all. If we replaced `user:fakeUsername` with `user:1234567890` you'd get [zero results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1234567890), even though there is [no such user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1234567890).

It is not, however, intended as a search for *users*, it is a search for *posts*.  As such, `user:...` is just one of the possible filters you can apply to search.  What should happen when you used a userid for an account that has no (visible) posts? Or used other filters in addition to `user:...` that caused the result to be empty?

For searches with no valid filters and no other terms, the search *always* results in a result page with all the posts matching.

If you expected `user:...` to search for users and not posts, then you need to go to the [users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users), which has a search box that gives you user accounts; this includes telling you that a username doesn't exist:

> [image]

Comment: Why is this an expected behaviour? If I do a Wikipedia or Google search for "fdojicvxj354353425xvc" I get no results. When I do the search on StackOverflow I get all results. SERIOUSLY?! - You think this is reasonable?

Comment: @AT: when I search for `fdojicvxj354353425xvc` I get [no results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fdojicvxj354353425xvc). It even says [0 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiRXc.png). Only when you use one of the search operators, but give it wrong input, and _no other search criteria_, would you get everything, because the search operator is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a user on the basis of (part of) their username you can go to [/users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users). Here is an entry field to search on username. Do note however that usernames are not unique, and can be [changed from time to time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518).

[image]